# Min and Max values for integer variable at compile time in C++

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

Is there a simple, clean way of determining at compile time the max and min values for a variable of some (otherwise unknown at the moment) integer variable or type? Using templates?

For example:

```
// Somewhere in a large project is:
typedef unsigned long XType;
typedef char YType;
// ...

// Somewhere else
   XType a;
   YType b;
   LONGLONG c,d,e,f;
   c = MinOfType(a); // Same as c = 0;
   d = MaxOfType(a); // Same as d = 0xffffffff;
   e = MinOfType(b); // Same as e = -128;
   f = MaxOfType(b); // Same as f = 127;
// Also would be nice
   e = MinOfType(YType); // Same as e = -128; // Using the typename directly
// Or perhaps
   e = MinOfType<YType>(); // Same as e = -128; // Using the typename directly
```

Comment: The value of a variable can't be known at compile time, but constants can.

Comment: The "value" of the variable is not needed in the above code. But is not the type of a variable, as in my example, known at compile time. These variables are not polymorphic classes, just one of the basic integer types. Or am I missing something (very possible). I think I have the numeric_limits working for case where the typename is used directly. Now can I do something like: e=numeric_limits<TypeOf(b)>::max(); ?

Comment: Surely the type "a" or "b" is known by the compiler, at compile time. Otherwise the compiler would not be able to generate code using these variables at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [boost integer_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/integer/integer_traits.html).

Answer (score 15):

Use std::numeric_limits, it is there for exactly this type of requirement. You can take a look at this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85084kd6(VS.80).aspx) for the usage.

Comment: AFAIK, those are not *compile-time*, though (if OP himself realizes what exactly he wants).

Comment: Not compile-time, but fairly close to it if optimisations are enabled.

Comment: RaphaelSP: if compile-time is actually required, such as for a template parameter or enumerator, then it doesn't matter what optimizations are enabled---either the expression is or it isn't.  Compare to constexprs in C++0x.

Comment: Good point. I just translated "compile-time" to "fast" (given the code snippet does not do sensible use of the "compile-time" bit).

Answer (score 3):

See this question [maximum value of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855459/maximum-value-of-int) - you can also use "min" in the places where the answers used "max"

Answer (score 0):

Include header `<limits>` to reach template class [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). The numeric type of your variable is used to find a specialization of that template class that will provide the maximum value via function [`max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) and the minimum value via [`min()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min), in addition to several other facets of the type.

Note that the interpretation for *minimum* is different for integral and floating point types. For the former, it's the most negative value for a signed type, and zero for an unsigned type, but for the latter, it's the smallest representable value, which is very close to zero.

Comment: Wrong. It is not compile time.

Comment: True, and the client code above could not distinguish evaluation at run time from compile time. All the implementations for `numeric_limits` I've seen are functions exposing constants defined at compile-time, but I don't think it was a mistake that the standard mandates those values be exposed through functions as opposed to constant member values -- in particular, to accommodate the floating point types or some other non-ICE.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to c++11, you can use a combination of `decltype` and `std::numeric_limits`.  Rewriting your sample code would look like this:

```
#include <limits>

typedef unsigned long XType;
typedef char YType;

XType a;
YType b;
LONGLONG c,d,e,f;
c = std::numeric_limits< decltype(a) >::min(); // Same as c = 0;
d = std::numeric_limits< decltype(a) >::max(); // Same as d = 0xffffffff;
e = std::numeric_limits< decltype(b) >::min(); // Same as e = -128;
f = std::numeric_limits< decltype(b) >::max(); // Same as f = 127;
e = std::numeric_limits< YType >::min(); // Same as e = -128; // Using the typename directly
```

[`decltype`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype) will pull the type from an expression, snagging the variable type in this case, and let you use it in other places that expect a type such as a template.  And it all happens at compile time such that you could assign it to a [`constexpr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constexpr#constexpr_-_Generalized_constant_expressions).

```
constexpr decltype(a) g = std::numeric_limits< decltype(a) >::min();
```

Here `g` would be of the same type as `a`,  would have the value 0, and all be determined at compile time.