# Conversion from +2147483648 to -2147483648 predictability

Tags: c

Is the behavior described below predictable?

**I've edited the numbers to be the limit of 2147483648. It still seems to work. Is that predictable?**

a.out execution

```
e1r4p22% ./a.out
-2147483648
4
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 2147483648;
    i = -i;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean "predictable" as in "tellable from code," in which case the answer is: yes, it is. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855459/maximum-value-of-int.

Comment: The number is well away from the max 4-byt int limit of 2147483647, so it should negate without any "odd" effects.  (In fact, *any* positive value should negate OK.)  So I don't see anything strange or unexpected.

Comment: Of course, try it with 2147483648 and you will see something different.

Comment: `printf("%lu\n", sizeof(int));` has undefined behavior on systems where `size_t` is not `unsigned long`. Either use the correct format for `size_t`, namely `"%zu"`, or cast the value: `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(int));`

Comment: changing the question in a way that invalidates all answers is lame - you should have asked a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed your question, which invalidates the previous answers.

The behavior of your program is not predictable in general.

The C standard only guarantees that `int` can represent values in the range `-32767` to `+32767` (16 bits). On such a system, the constant `2147483648` is of type `long` or `long long`.

Even if `int` is 32 bits, no padding bits, and two's-complement, `2147483648` is outside the range of `int`, and may be of type `long` or `long long`.

This:

```
int i = 2147483648;
```

implicitly *converts* the `long` or `long long` value to `int`. The result is implementation-defined -- or it can raise an implementation-defined signal.

On many systems, the implementation-defined result is going to be `-2147483648`. IF it is, then this:

```
i = -i;
```

attempts to negate that value, yielding a result that's outside the range of `int`. Unlike a conversion, an overflowing arithmetic operator such as unary `-` has *undefined behavior* for signed types.

It's very likely that the program will behave as it does on your system, but no, it's not predictable as far as the C standard is concerned. The compiler is free to *assume* that your program's behavior is well defined, and generate code based on that assumption, so it's actually plausible that it could behave in some unexpected manner.

Also:

```
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(int));
```

This will work correctly *if* `size_t` (the result of the `sizeof` operator) is `unsigned long` on your system. If it isn't, then again, you have undefined behavior. The correct format for `size_t` is `"%zu"`:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));
```

That was introduced in C99, so some implementations (particularly Microsoft's) may not support it. You can also convert the argument to the appropriate type with a cast:

```
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(int));
```

Whatever this code is trying to accomplish, there's almost certainly a clearer way to do it. If you want to be able to manipulate integers with values of `2147483648`, `long long` or `int64_t` is guaranteed to be big enough.

Comment: It would be good to point out that there is `int32_t` which have 32-bits width, if it is available on the system.

Comment: `int32_t` can't hold the value `2147483648`.

Comment: Ups. Sorry - I still had in mind `2 147 483 148` (`0x7FFFFEOC`) not `2 147 483 647` (`0x80000000`) :( In this case `int64_t`.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of an int is 2 147 483 647, according to `limits.h` and with `sizeof(int) = 4`. So yes, it's predictable, since 2 147 483 148 < 2 147 483 647.

Comment: According to `limits.h` *on your system*. The C standard only guarantees that `INT_MAX >= 32767`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Look at the question.

Comment: Ok, on your system and the OP's system. *If* `sizeof (int) == 4` *and* `int` has no padding bits then `INT_MAX == 2147483647` (or more if `CHAR_BIT > 8`). But the question doesn't presume that `int` is 4 bytes, and the program's behavior is not predictable for all implementations.

Comment: The question presume that `int` is 4 bytes, look the output of `printf("%lu\n", sizeof(int));`, so I guess the OP doesn't care about other system. That becomes ridiculous.

Comment: The question doesn't *presume* that `int` is 4 bytes. That's part of the program's output, and the OP is asking whether the output is predictable.

Comment: Read the question. I see no such presumption.

Comment: @nouney he code should not just assume something that isn't guaranteed by standard. One of the problems we (industry) had (have?) is assuming that `sizeof(void *) == 4` or that `volatile` means atomic, both statements were true on majority of systems used at a time.