# C preprocessor define for value of a given type where every byte is 0xFF?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Let's say there's a data type defined as such:

```
typedef int my_integer_type;
```

Somewhere else, there exists code like this

```
#define MAX_MY_INTEGER_TYPE 0xFFFFFFFF
```

However, if my_integer_type later is changed to 8 bytes instead of 4, MAX_MY_INTEGER_TYPE will need to be updated as well.  Is there a way for MAX_MY_INTEGER_TYPE to be a bit smarter, to basically represent the number of bytes in my_integer_type all set to 0xFF?

I realize there are other traditional ways to get the maximum integer size (like here: [maximum value of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855459/maximum-value-of-int)), but my actual use case is a bit more complex and I cannot apply those solutions.

Comment: This seems the maximum for an **unsigned** type. If that is the case, then just `#define MAX_MY_INTEGER ((my_unsigned_integer)-1)`.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Did you mean `#define MAX_MY_INTEGER_TYPE ((my_integer_type)0 - 1)`?

EDIT: Nevermind, I see you were casting the -1.  Is it Friday yet?

Comment: If you want to set all bits to 1 in an unsigned type, you can use  `#define MAX_MY_INTEGER_TYPE -1` I'm not certain what the guarantees are for signed types, though I suspect it'd also set all bits to 1 on 2's complement systems.

Comment: Please specify your goal: 1) "value of a given type where every byte is 0xFF" 2) Maximum positive of `my_integer_type` that is some `unsigned` type 3) Maximum positive of `my_integer_type` that is some `signed` type 4) Maximum positive of `my_integer_type` that is some `signed` or `unsigned` type OR 5) something else?

Answer (score 2):

No, for signed integer types there is basically no way to calculate the maximum values for the type. This is the main reason why all the predefined `MAX`-macros such as `INT_MAX` exist. To avoid the maintenance problem you could go the other way round

```
#include <limits.h>

#define MY_INTEGER_TYPE_MAX 0xFFFF...FFF  // whatever number of 'F' you chose

#if MY_INTEGER_TYPE_MAX <= SCHAR_MAX
typedef signed char my_integer_type;
#elsif MY_INTEGER_TYPE_MAX <= SHRT_MAX
typedef signed short int my_integer_type;
#elsif MY_INTEGER_TYPE_MAX <= INT_MAX
typedef signed int my_integer_type;
#elsif MY_INTEGER_TYPE_MAX <= LONG_MAX
typedef signed long int my_integer_type;
#elsif MY_INTEGER_TYPE_MAX <= LLONG_MAX
typedef signed long long int my_integer_type;
#else
typedef intmax_t my_integer_type;
#endif
```

You see that it is not a very long list of cases that you have to differentiate.

Comment: You should look at my answer. I calculate the maximum value for a signed number.

Comment: @Marcos, you should look at the C standard :) In your answer you make assumptions about signed integers that are not fulfilled on all platforms. In particular, you are assuming that the type has no padding bits and your left shift has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the maximum size of an integer like using bit-wise operations.

For an unsigned integer you can do it like this:

```
const unsigned int MAX_SIZE = ~0;
```

or, you can do it like this if your compiler does not complain:

```
const unsigned int MAX_SIZE = -1;
```

**EDIT**

For your particular case, it seems you want to be able to calculate the maximum value of a signed type. Assuming the sign is calculated using 2's complement (as is in most systems), you can use this methods:

```
const my_integer_type MAX_MY_INTEGER_TYPE =
   ~((my_integer_type)1 << (sizeof(my_integer_type) * CHAR_BIT) - 1);
```

So, what I do here is calculate the size of the type. Whatever the size is, I'm going to subtract 1 from that. I use the resulting number to shift a 1 to the left most position. Then I invert the whole thing.

Let's say that my_integer_type is 1 bytes. That is 8 bits, meaning that the shift amount is 7. I take the 1 and shift it. The result of the shift looks like this: `0x80`. When you invert it, you get this: `0x7f`. And that is the maximum value (of course, assuming it uses 2's complement).

Note that I did not used the preprocessor. Unfortunately, the preprossor is a simple find and replace tool that is not aware of types in C. So, you'll have to use constants.

Comment: `(unsigned)(~0) >> 1` does not work for what the OP requests. `~0` is an `int`, and you cast it to `unsigned`, but the OP needs a custom type. You could start with `~ (my_integer_type) 0` to get all ones in the OP’s type, but then you do not have an unsigned type to cast it to, so you cannot shift the bits safely.

Comment: You were right. But I think I fixed it now. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases that the C standard allows. Integer types may have padding bits, and left shifting a signed integer type into the sign bit makes the behavior undefined. (And also you shouldn't use `8` as a constant but `CHAR_BIT`)

Comment: @JensGustedt You're right about the size of a `char`. I've fixed that. But I don't understand what you mean by padding bits. I though those were only added to structs for data alignment. Btw, I didn't know C had a constant for the size of `char`, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Marcos, padding bits and not padding bytes, these are two completely different concepts, unfortunately. In C, integer types can have unused bytes in their representation that count up for the size of the data, but that are not use for the representation of the value. A use case for this are parity bits, e.g, or cases where architectures just mask the sign bit of a signed integer type to obtain the corresponding unsigned type.

Comment: Also my objection that your `<<` operation has undefined behavior still holds. You shift the `1` into the sign bit, this is not "allowed", already for the operation itself. Even if your architecture might tolerate this, the resulting value, a `1` followed by all `0` is not necessarily a valid value for your type, but a so-called trap representation. In most two's complement architectures it is the min value, but it hasn't to be. Doing any operation with trap representation can "trap" as the name indicates that is simply stop the execution of of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear is OP wants "every byte is 0xFF" or the maximum integer value.

1) [Edit] Assuming "every byte is 0xFF" is OP's goal, @Eric Postpischil idea is sound and simple

```
// Better name: MY_INTEGER_TYPE_ALL_BITS_SET
#define MAX_MY_INTEGER_TYPE (~ (my_integer_type) 0)
```

2) Interesting OP is asking for "value of a given type where every byte is 0xFF?" and then proceeds to call it "MAX_MY_INTEGER_TYPE".  This *does* sound like an `unsigned` as the maximum `signed` value is rarely (if ever) "every byte is 0xFF".  Using `-1` as suggested by @H2CO3 looks good.

```
#define MAX_MY_INTEGER ((my_integer_type) 0 - 1).
```

3) Not yet answered: if OP wants max value and `my_integer_type` *could* be signed (and not assuming 2's complement).

Answer (score -2):

You could use predefined types from stdint.h header.

```
typedef int32_t my_integer_type;
```

And you are sure that your type will have 4 byes on all platforms.

Comment: This is not what OP wants to accomplish

Comment: The reason I cannot do this is that the typedef is not under my control - it's provided as part of a library from a third party, and I cannot control it in any way.

Comment: Maybe. But #define MAX_MY_INTEGER_TYPE 0xFFFFFFFF isn't really max value of int type. 0xFFFFFFFF = -1 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). I always use stdint types to avoid unpleasant bugs. Someoe answered before: 
`#define MAX_MY_INTEGER_TYPE (my_integer_type)(-1)`