# Is there a standard macro in C or C++ represent the max and min value of int32_t, int64_t?

Tags: c++, c

Is there any macro in C or C++ represent the max and min value of int32_t and int64_t? I know it can be literally defined by oneself, but it's better if there is a standard macro. Please note I'm not asking about max of int, long ,etc. but `intXX_t`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855459/maximum-value-of-int

Comment: `INTxx_MAX`, `INTxx_MIN` in `<stdint.h>`

Comment: Beware about `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` and old C++ compilers

Comment: @BenVoigt: There is no such macro im C.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sorry, I did not get both expressions are related. Mostly, because there are actually `__STD_`-macros in C.

Comment: Reopened: the linked duplicate does not answer OP's question for C

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++, there is `std::numeric_limits::min()` and `std::numeric_limits::max()` in the [`<limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) header:

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::min() << std::endl;
```

and so on. In C, the header [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) defines `INT32_MIN`, `INT32_MAX` etc. These are also available in the C++ [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) header.

Answer (score 6):

In C++ you can use header `<limits>` and class `std::numeric_limts` declared in this header.

To know the max and min values of types int32_t and int64_t you can write for example

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>

//...

std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min() << std::endl;
```

In C you should include header `<stdint.h>` and use corresponding macros defined in the header as for example

```
INT32_MIN
INT32_MAX
INT64_MIN
INT64_MAX
```