# c++ the square of double generate a negative number

Tags: c++, double

Maybe this is an idiot question but I can't figure out the problem.

Running the following code:

```
    double num = 0.0;
    double den = 0.0;
    std::string line;
    if (std::getline (file,line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss>>valueLine[j++]){} //Read and parse an entire line
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUe; i++)
        {
            num = num + (valueLine[i+1]/1000);
            den = den + ((valueLine[i+1]*valueLine[i+1])/1000000);
        }
        [...]
```

I obtained that `((valueLine[i+1]*valueLine[i+1])/1000000) = -1010` when `valueLine[i+1] = 57314`.
Where is the error? Why I obtained a negative result? What I'm missing?

Comment: what type is `valueLine`? My guess is `valueLine` is an integral type, in which case you are overflowing.

Comment: Post a [MCVE], or it didn't happen.

Comment: @rlbond valueLine is a pointer to an `int` . I also tried the cast to `double` when I do the division 1000. But nothing change and I still have a negative number.

Comment: Cast to double before the multiply, not before the division (after the multiply)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that:

```
3284894596  = 57314 * 57314
```

while in my machine for example, `INT_MAX` is:

```
2147483647
```

which means, that you are a victim of overflow ( that's why you did good for posting in Stackoverflow :) ).

In your machine `INT_MAX` may have another value, but again it is smaller than 57314².

You may also want to take a look here:

[maximum value of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855459/maximum-value-of-int)

---

Your move to divide won't do any good, since the multiplication will happen first. You could use `unsigned int`. On my machine:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() << std::endl;
    unsigned int a = 57314;
    std::cout << a * a << std::endl;
}
```

gives:

```
4294967295
3284894596
```

PS - You could divide each term with `100`, but you will lose some accuracy if you are not careful.

Comment: I know that, but I add `/1000000` in order to avoid the overflow. Why this is not working? What should I do to avoid this issue?

Comment: Updated @Mattia, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are more than likely hitting a overflow. Really large numbers squared together can create a number that cannot be stored in the memory allocated for your `valueLine[i+1]` so it "overflows" into the negative number.

Things you could try:

- Using an unsigned long type (e.g., uint64_t) instead of double
- If you need signed values try using a larger type

Check out and MSDN article relating to type sizes: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fh3a000.aspx)

Comment: `double` is a floating-point type. There's no such thing as an `unsigned double`.

Comment: No, I only know what you wrote.