# c++ getting a negative value when adding two absolute (positive) values

Tags: c++, int, cmath

I am getting a strange problem. I am getting a negative value when adding two absolute (positive) values. I am trying to solve this exercise from codingame (link: https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/network-cabling).

I tried debugging and I got this:

```
X[i]: 19715507  X[j]: 938059973   // This one is good
temp: 918344466   

Y[i]: 470868309  Y[j]: -816049599 //Something is wrong here
temp: -2089704922
```

This code is probably not a good solution to the exercise and I will need to improve it, but I still can't figure it out why the value is negative.

Please help.

Thank you.

Code:

```
int main()
{

    int N;
    int X[100000];
    int Y[100000];

    cin >> N; cin.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {   //reading all input

        cin >> X[i] >> Y[i]; cin.ignore();
    }

    int ilgis=0;   //ilgis means length

    for(int i=0; i<N-1; i++){       //"min" is set to a very high value 
                                    //so it could find a lower value later
                                    // "not the best solution"

        int min=99999999999999999999;   //shortest distance between houses
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){    // here I am trying to find the shortest 
                                   // distance from one house to another

            if(j!=i){     //I can't count distance from the same house because 
                          // it would be 0

                int temp=0;
                                    //counting the distance differently if the 
                                    //value is negative or positive

                if(X[i]<=0&&X[j]<=0) temp+=abs(abs(X[i])-abs(X[j]));
                else if(X[i]<=0&&X[j]>=0) temp+=abs(X[i])+abs(X[j]);
                else if(X[i]>=0&&X[j]>=0) temp+=abs(X[i]-X[j]);
                else if(X[i]>=0&&X[j]<=0) temp+=(X[i])+abs(X[j]);

                                       //same with y axis

                if(Y[i]<=0&&Y[j]<=0) temp+=abs(abs(Y[i])-abs(Y[j]));
                else if(Y[i]<=0&&Y[j]>=0) temp+=abs(Y[i])+abs(Y[j]);
                else if(Y[i]>=0&&Y[j]>=0) temp+=abs(Y[i]-Y[j]);
                else if(Y[i]>=0&&Y[j]<=0) temp+=(Y[i])+abs(Y[j]); 

                if(min>temp) min=temp;  
                }
            }                   //if i found the shortesst distance between 
                                //houses I add that value to overall distance
                                // and continue until all houses are checked
        ilgis+=min;

        }
    cout<<ilgis<<endl;
}
```

Input of the exercise:

```
 8
-28189131 593661218
102460950 1038903636
938059973 -816049599
-334087877 -290840615
842560881 -116496866
-416604701 690825290
19715507 470868309
846505116 -694479954
```

Comment: On a normal PC, the `int` type is a signed ***32-bit*** type, which means it can have values from around minus two billion to plus two billion. `99999999999999999999` is not within that range.

Comment: Do you think `99999999999999999999` could be stored in an `int` without overflow? You probably need `long long int`, or `long int`. (But these may have the same size as `int`).

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855459/maximum-value-of-int basically you're overflowing the max value of `int` so it wraps around

Comment: check what is the value of `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` and compare that to the result you expect to get

Comment: Furthermore, overflowing a signed integer type leads to *undefined behavior*. What most likely will happen is that it becomes negative as that's how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) (the most common way to represent negative numbers) works.

Comment: @Arnav Borborah isn't the size of `long long int` twice the size of `int`?

Comment: `long long int` can be the same as `int` if the CPU does not have support for larger integers. There is no requirement that it has to be bigger just that it is at least as big.

Comment: std::numeric_limits<int>::max()    worked :). Thank you!

Comment: I also needed to make other `int` to be `long int`

Comment: std::numeric_limits<int>::max():  2,147,483,647; std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max():  2,147,483,647;  std::numeric_limits<int>::digits (Non-sign bits in int): 31 std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min(): -9,223,372,036,854,775,808, std::numeric_limits<uintptr_t>::max(): 18,446,744,073,709,551,615;      std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::digits (Non-sign bits in int): 63
std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::digits (Non-sign bits in int): 64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum value for `int` is 2147483647 (which is 2^31-1, assuming `int` has 32 bits width). You can check it with

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

You might want to `min` with this value here. And also use `long long` as your type for calculations here.

Comment: the maximum value for int could be 2147483647-5 as well, `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` may return different values

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :)

Comment: @user463035818: yep, with probability 10^-128.

Comment: @YvesDaoust why risking UB in 10^-128 of all cases when you can make it 0.

Comment: @user463035818: because of the base-3 computers, such as the Setun. A full ports of C++ to these machines is unlikely.