# Checking for integer overflow in Android NDK cod

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, integer-overflow

I'm doing some integer overflow checking in C++ using the Android NDK. For space reasons, I can't use the full C++ stdlib, so I can't use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1855465/158703).

What is my best alternative?

Comment: Have you tried copying just the `numeric_limits` code and adding it to a custom header file?  That way you don't have to `include` all of `cstdlib`.

Comment: Is that safe considering the code might run on both ARM and x86?

Comment: I'm looking at the limits header file, and I don't see anything specific to ARM vs x86. However, my machine doesn't appear to have a c++config.h header file, so I can't tell for sure.
How much extra space does the limits header take up anyway? Have you compared with vs without?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't used a fixed size type (e.g. `int32_t`)?

Comment: @Michael Can you write up your comment as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: "Have you tried copying just the numeric_limits code and adding it to a custom header file? That way you don't have to include all of cstdlib". The OP is trying to avoid *the* stdlib, i.e. libc++_shared.so. This is very different from trying to avoid the header file cstdlib, which is basically an empty file (it's just `using ::blah;` definitions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by copying and hardcoding the limit values from `limits.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the static STL instead of the shared one. Only the pieces you use will be included in your app and the linker will strip the rest.

Comment: This is worth trying, but it didn't work for me. Unfortunately, I don't recall the exact reason why, but none of the STL options worked.

Comment: Should file a bug.