# What is Wrong With my Code?, How can i improve it any further?

Tags: c++

The problem is that my program does not give accurate average for numbers with more than 9 digits.

Can somebody point out what am I doing wrong and how do I fix that? Is there anything I can do to improve the code any further?

The code is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "                 Average Finder           \n";  //So that the title is displayed properly.
    int NUM1,NUM2,AVG;  /*I am defining the variables as integers, seemed like the best option.
                          Should I use long float? Does that even work?*/ 
    cout << "Type the First Number:   "; // for the display
    cin >> NUM1; // the program asks for the first user input and stores it in integer variable NUM1
    cout << " \n";
    cout << "Type the Second Number:  ";
    cin >> NUM2;  // the program asks for the second user input and stores it in integer variable NUM2
    cout << " \n";
    AVG = ((NUM1+NUM2)/2); //this line calculates their average
    cout << "The Average of given numbers is = ";
    cout << AVG;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the command line executions.

```
PS D:\Workspace\Coding\C++> .\ALG001.EXE

                 Average Finder
Type the First Number:   1111111111

Type the Second Number:  1111111111

The Average of given numbers is = -1036372537
```

Comment: Have you [considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855459/maximum-value-of-int) what is the [maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/1563833) you can store in a variable of type `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NUM1` and `NUM2` are of type `int`. `int` variables have a maximum value, on most systems it is `2147483647`.

When `NUM1 = 1111111111`  and `NUM2 = 1111111111`, then `NUM1 + NUM2`  will be bigger than the the maximum value `2147483647`. This is called overflow.

Technically in c++ this is undefined behaviour, but on most systems it will wrap around giving you negative values and explaining your output.

If you want your variables to store larger values, use `long` or even `long long`.

Comment: And when int64_t is too small, you can use gmpxx.h and its type mpz_class.  Items of this type are a multiprecision integer.

Comment: So, The user input exceeded the maximum limit, Like a cup being over-filled. Thus resulting in an Overflow.

And the solution was to simply increase the volume of cup.

Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, although (technically) the sum of your two numbers exceeded the maximum limit, not the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use floating point for the average.  And beware of *integer division*:

```
double average = 0.0;
average = (1 + 2 + 3) / 3.0;
std::cout << average << "\n";
```

With integer division, `1 / 3 == 0`.

Comment: Can You please elaborate. I don't think I understood the logic behind that.